# Xamarin OnLaunched event

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking to create styles (and eventually some of the pages) using C# code behind.  Was looking at the write up on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-resource-dictionary and when I duplicate that code it gives me an error that LaunchActivatedEventArgs is unknown.

My starting App.xaml.cs file:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace FieldDataTemplateSelectorSample
{
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
           // add styles here
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't know the type or namespace for LaunchActivatedEventArgs.  If I look at the list of potential fixes, it suggests that I add a using for Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation to the list of usings.  If I do that, then it complains about OnLaunched not having a suitable method to override.  If I take out the override, and change the signature to

```
using System;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using FieldDataTemplateSelectorSample.AppStyles;

namespace FieldDataTemplateSelectorSample
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }

        protected void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Resources = InitStyles.GetAppStyles();
        }
    }
}
```

The application compiles but the OnLaunched method never gets hit if I put a break point in there.  What am I missing?  Right now I'm using a UWP project for getting my feet wet, and eventually will add android and ios.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @ToolmakerSteve.  That did it.  If you'd like to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`OnLaunched` is a Windows or UWP API, not a Xamarin API.

Put your code in `OnStart` instead.

For cross-platform code, find "Windows.Forms" docs, instead of "Windows App Development" docs.

---

OR sometimes you'll want code in your .UWP or .Windows project - but I don't think this is one of those situations.